# Pandas Merge returning only null values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to use Pandas to merge a products packing information with each order record for a given product.  The data frame information is below.

```
     BreakerOrders.info()
   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 3774010 entries, 0 to 3774009
    Data columns (total 2 columns):
    Material    object
    Quantity    float64
    dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
    memory usage: 86.4+ MB

     manh.info()
   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 1381 entries, 0 to 1380
    Data columns (total 4 columns):
    Material       1381 non-null object
    SUBPACK_QTY    202 non-null float64
    PACK_QTY       591 non-null float64
    PALLET_QTY     809 non-null float64
    dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
    memory usage: 43.2+ KB
```

When attempting the merge using the code below, I get the following table with all NaN values for packaging quantities.

```
   BreakerOrders.merge(manh,how='left',on='Material')


    Material    Quantity    SUBPACK_QTY   PACK_QTY  PALLET_QTY
    HOM230CP    5.0             NaN         NaN        NaN
    QO115       20.0            NaN         NaN        NaN
    QO2020CP    20.0            NaN         NaN        NaN
    QO220CP     50.0            NaN         NaN        NaN
    HOM115CP    50.0            NaN         NaN        NaN
    HOM120      100.0           NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Then there are no matches of `Material` between the two dataframes.  Could be due to whitespace or some other annoying thing.  If this is unexpected, then you need to provide an example.  Read [mcve]

Comment: Try this for both dataframe before merging `df['Material'] = df['Material'].astype('str') `

Comment: What's the result of `manh[manh['Material'].isin({'HOM230CP', 'QO115',  'QO2020CP', 'QO220CP', 'HOM115CP'})]`?

Comment: Both data frames have been adjusted to a string prior to running the merge, and this does not fix the error.  When trying the above block of code, I get the expected output of packaging quantities.

Comment: And what is the result of `BreakerOrders.merge(manh.fillna(-1000), how='left', on='Material')`?

Comment: This returns the same original data frame with NaN for all fields in manh

Comment: should not make a difference, but did you try using `join` instead of merge?

Comment: If you're still getting NaNs when you do a left join after filling `manh` with `-1000`, then you have mismatching elements in the two tables' `'Material'` columns. Full stop. There is no argument, no matter what you think is going on. What if you change `how='left'` to `how='inner'`?

Comment: That is false, all of the Materials are in both tables and formatted in the same manner.  An inner join returns a completely blank table.

Comment: "An inner join returns a completely blank table." Then apparently it isn't false, and you have some work to do to understand why you think it is, and what the problem with your data formatting is. Please see the link provided by @piRSquared if you would like to receive further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same and I was able to solve it by just flipping the DFs. so instead of:

```
df2 = df.merge(df1)
```

try

```
df2 = df1.merge(df)
```

Looks silly, but it solved my issue.